# how to test rest controller with custom annotation in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have controller defined like below

```
 @GetMapping(value="")
public ResponseEntity<JsonResponse> getLocations(@RequestHeader(value="id") String id, @LocationType @RequestParam(value="locationType" ) String P_STS_AREA_TYP) {

    ...
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

@LocationType is custom annotation, definition

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = LocationTypeValidator.class)
public @interface LocationType {
String message() default "";
Class<?>[] groups() default {};
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```

}

it's working perfectly, check location type when app runs normally. but when i tried to test it using Juint, it stops working.

```
@Test
public void should_return_input_invalid_exception_for_invalid_location_type_for_get_location_endpoint() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/something/something/something")
            .param("locationType", "something")
            .header("id", "12345678"))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

}
```

it pass validation and doesn't enter error handling logic like it does when app run normally with same location type query parameter.

annotations used on test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { something.class, something.class})
```

mockito as mock framework

does anyone know how to make custom annotation work in Junit?

@Plog, my validator definition

```
public class LocationTypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<LocationType, String> {

@Autowired
InputValidator inputValidator;
@Override
public void initialize(LocationType locationType) {

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String locationType, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return inputValidator.validateLocationType(locationType);
}
```

}

i can't setValidator, since it doesn't implements Validator interface

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, just no validation

Answer (score -1):

You need to make your custom validator available to your mockMvc instance. You should be able to do this by autowiring Spring's LocalValidatorFactoryBean

```
@Autowired
private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

...

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController)
                  .setValidator(validator).build()
}
```

Comment: i can't setValidator(validator), since i am implementing as: 
    LocationTypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<LocationType, String>

Comment: Ah whoops, my bad. What are you annotating your test class with?

Comment: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { something.class, something.class})

Comment: I've updated my answer. If this doesn't work have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161752/spring-mockmvc-how-to-mock-custom-validators-running-outside-of-controllers/37896455?noredirect=1#answer-37896455. It is to do with mocking a constraint validator but should shed some light on how to get your mockMvc instance to recognise it.